# index.html is not loading as default home page

Tags: html, server, hosting

I've offered to help a friend by hosting their website (using my account with iPage), however there's an issue I can't resolve. The homepage, `FirstnameSurname.com`, returns a 404 error.

The namepointers are working correctly as I can access `www.FirstnameSurname.com/index.html`, however when trying to load `www.FirstnameSurname.com` it returns the 404.

I've tried changing the folder name (on the server) from `FSurname` to `FirstnameSurname` so it matches the domain but it fixes nothing.

Poking around in the htcaccess file I've not been able to fix it either, even when adding `DirectoryIndex index.html`.

What is going on? How can I fix this problem? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This might work on htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: I don't know what sort of voodoo this is or how it works, but it does. Amazing. Thanks!